# Continuously displaying sensor values in a Text View with react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

In the code below I am trying to get the accelerometer values and timestamp and display them in a Text view. If I comment out the line `setVal(timestamp)` then the values displayed with `console.log({x, y, z, timestamp})` are correct (as expected). However, if I uncomment `setVal(timestamp)`, then the values displayed with `console.log` eventually become all the same over time.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I guess that `setVal(timestamp)` is somehow overriding the values of the variable `timestamp`. Is there a more correct and better way of doing this?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {accelerometer} from 'react-native-sensors';

export default function App(props) {

  const [val, setVal] = useState(1);

  const subscription = accelerometer.subscribe(({x, y, z, timestamp}) => {
    console.log({x, y, z, timestamp});
    setVal(timestamp);
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Timestamp: {val}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting the subscribe in a `useEffect` with an empty array as a dependency? I think the problem might be because you are creating a new subscribe in every render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't call setVal(timestamp), then it does not rerenders. But when you put this line, its gets rerender continuously.
Try replacing your code like this. So the subscription is done once not again and again.

```
useEffect(()=> {
   const subscription = accelerometer.subscribe(({x, y, z, timestamp}) => {
   console.log({x, y, z, timestamp});
   setVal(timestamp);
 })},[])
```

Comment: It works with useEffect. Does this mean that instead of using useEffect, one could also define the component App as a class and just do the subscription once in the constructor ?

Comment: componentdidmount is the replcement of useEffect with empty braces []. So its better to 
use it in componentdidmount. You can use it in contructor though.